# setState() inside of componentDidUpdate()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm writing a script which moves dropdown below or above input depending on height of dropdown and position of the input on the screen. Also I want to set modifier to dropdown according to its direction.
But using `setState` inside of the `componentDidUpdate` creates an infinite loop(which is obvious)

I've found a solution in using `getDOMNode` and setting classname to dropdown directly, but i feel that there should be a better solution using React tools. Can anybody help me?

Here is a part of working code with `getDOMNode` (i 
a little bit neglected positioning logic to simplify code)

```
let SearchDropdown = React.createClass({
    componentDidUpdate(params) {
        let el = this.getDOMNode();
        el.classList.remove('dropDown-top');
        if(needToMoveOnTop(el)) {
            el.top = newTopValue;
            el.right = newRightValue;
            el.classList.add('dropDown-top');
        }
    },
    render() {
        let dataFeed = this.props.dataFeed;
        return (
            <DropDown >
                {dataFeed.map((data, i) => {
                    return (<DropDownRow key={response.symbol} data={data}/>);
                })}
            </DropDown>
        );
    }
});
```

and here is code with setstate (which creates an infinite loop)

```
let SearchDropdown = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            top: false
        };
    },
    componentDidUpdate(params) {
        let el = this.getDOMNode();
        if (this.state.top) {
           this.setState({top: false});
        }
        if(needToMoveOnTop(el)) {
            el.top = newTopValue;
            el.right = newRightValue;
            if (!this.state.top) {
              this.setState({top: true});
           }
        }
    },
    render() {
        let dataFeed = this.props.dataFeed;
        let class = cx({'dropDown-top' : this.state.top});
        return (
            <DropDown className={class} >
                {dataFeed.map((data, i) => {
                    return (<DropDownRow key={response.symbol} data={data}/>);
                })}
            </DropDown>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: I think the trick here is that `setState` will *always* trigger a re-render.  Rather than checking `state.top` and calling `setState` multiple times, just track what you want `state.top` to be in a local variable, then once at the end of `componentDidUpdate` call `setState` only if your local variable doesn't match `state.top`.  As it stands right now, you immediately reset `state.top` after the first re-render, which puts you in the infinite loop.

Comment: See the two different implementations of `componentDidUpdate` in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/9252/).

Comment: damn it! local variable solves the whole problem, how hadn't i figured it out by mysef! Thank you!

Comment: I think you should accept the answer below. If you read it again I think you'll find it does answer the initial question sufficiently.

Comment: Why has no one suggested moving the condition into `componentShouldUpdate`?

Comment: @KatyaPavlenko thanks for the local variable suggestion (instead of state)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can use `setState`inside `componentDidUpdate`. The problem is that somehow you are creating an infinite loop because there's no break condition.

Based on the fact that you need values that are provided by the browser once the component is rendered, I think your approach about using `componentDidUpdate` is correct, it just needs better handling of the condition that triggers the `setState`.

Comment: what do you mean by 'break condition'? checking if state is already set and not resetting it?

Comment: I agree with this, my only additional comment would be that the adding/removing of classes is probably unnecessary in `componentDidUpdate` and can just be added as needed in `render` instead.

Comment: but class adding/removing depends on dropdown position which is checked in in componentDidUpdate, you suggest to check it twice? And as i understand, componentDidUpdate is called AFTER render(), so it's useless to add/remove class in render()

Comment: i have added my code with setstate, can you check it and point me to my mistake? or show me some example which wouldn't cause loop

Comment: componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { if ( prevState.x!== this.state.x) { //Do Something } }

Answer (score 96):

The `componentDidUpdate` signature is `void::componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState)`. With this you will be able to test which props/state are dirty and call `setState` accordingly.

#### Example:

```
componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState) {
    if (previousProps.data !== this.props.data) {
        this.setState({/*....*/})
    }
}
```

Comment: `componentDidMount` doesn't have any arguments, and is only called when the component is created, so can't be used for the described purpose.

Comment: @Jules Thanks ! I used to write `componentDidMount` , so when I wrote the answer the famous name cascaded  Again, Thanks & Great catch up!

Comment: ```componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if ( prevState.x!==  this.state.x) {
    //Do Something
    }
  }
```

Comment: I know your concern @AshokR . You reduce the arg name. but "prev" can mean prevent not previous.. hhh . .kidding :)

Answer (score 62):

If you use `setState` inside `componentDidUpdate` it updates the component, resulting in a call to `componentDidUpdate` which subsequently calls `setState` again resulting in the infinite loop. You should conditionally call `setState` and ensure that the condition violating the call occurs eventually e.g:

```
componentDidUpdate: function() {
    if (condition) {
        this.setState({..})
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

In case you are only updating the component by sending props to it(it is not being updated by setState, except for the case inside componentDidUpdate), you can call `setState` inside `componentWillReceiveProps` instead of `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: old question but componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated and componentWillRecieveProps should be used.  You cannot setState inside this method.

Comment: You mean `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Answer (score 8):

This example will help you to understand the **React Life Cycle Hooks**.

You can `setState` in `getDerivedStateFromProps` method i.e. `static` and trigger the method after props change in `componentDidUpdate`.

In `componentDidUpdate` you will get **3rd** param which returns from `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`.

You can check this [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-life-cycle-cd7gc)

```js
// Child component
class Child extends React.Component {
  // First thing called when component loaded
  constructor(props) {
    console.log("constructor");
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: this.props.value,
      color: "green"
    };
  }

  // static method
  // dont have access of 'this'
  // return object will update the state
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    console.log("getDerivedStateFromProps");
    return {
      value: props.value,
      color: props.value % 2 === 0 ? "green" : "red"
    };
  }

  // skip render if return false
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log("shouldComponentUpdate");
    // return nextState.color !== this.state.color;
    return true;
  }

  // In between before real DOM updates (pre-commit)
  // has access of 'this'
  // return object will be captured in componentDidUpdate
  getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log("getSnapshotBeforeUpdate");
    return { oldValue: prevState.value };
  }

  // Calls after component updated
  // has access of previous state and props with snapshot
  // Can call methods here
  // setState inside this will cause infinite loop
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    console.log("componentDidUpdate: ", prevProps, prevState, snapshot);
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    console.log("getDerivedStateFromError");
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    console.log("componentDidCatch: ", error, info);
  }

  // After component mount
  // Good place to start AJAX call and initial state
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
    this.makeAjaxCall();
  }

  makeAjaxCall() {
    console.log("makeAjaxCall");
  }

  onClick() {
    console.log("state: ", this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid red", padding: "0px 10px 10px 10px" }}>
        <p style={{ color: this.state.color }}>Color: {this.state.color}</p>
        <button onClick={() => this.onClick()}>{this.props.value}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Parent component
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: 1 };

    this.tick = () => {
      this.setState({
        date: new Date(),
        value: this.state.value + 1
      });
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(this.tick, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid blue", padding: "0px 10px 10px 10px" }}>
        <p>Parent</p>
        <Child value={this.state.value} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Parent />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you need to check if the state already has the same value you are trying to set. If it's the same, there is no point to set state again for the same value.

Make sure to set your state like this:

```
let top = newValue /*true or false*/
if(top !== this.state.top){
    this.setState({top});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this.setState creates an infinite loop when used in ComponentDidUpdate when there is no break condition in the loop.
You can use redux to set a variable true in the if statement and then in the condition set the variable false then it will work.

Something like this.

```
if(this.props.route.params.resetFields){

        this.props.route.params.resetFields = false;
        this.setState({broadcastMembersCount: 0,isLinkAttached: false,attachedAffiliatedLink:false,affilatedText: 'add your affiliate link'});
        this.resetSelectedContactAndGroups();
        this.hideNext = false;
        this.initialValue_1 = 140;
        this.initialValue_2 = 140;
        this.height = 20
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. Please make componentDidUpdate an arrow function. That should work.

```
componentDidUpdate = (params) => {
    let el = this.getDOMNode();
    if (this.state.top) {
       this.setState({top: false});
    }
    if(needToMoveOnTop(el)) {
        el.top = newTopValue;
        el.right = newRightValue;
        if (!this.state.top) {
          this.setState({top: true});
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem where i have to center the toolTip. React setState in componentDidUpdate did put me in infinite loop, i tried condition it worked. But i found using in ref callback gave me simpler and clean solution, if you use inline function for ref callback you will face the  null problem for every component update. So use function reference in ref callback and set the state there, which will initiate the re-render

Answer (score -3):

You can use **setState** inside componentDidUpdate