# React Inline Style: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I have this error when i import the SCSS stylesheet in React Component:

> server.js:614             return /msie
>   [6-9]\b/.test(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
>                                        ^
>
> ReferenceError: window is not defined

This is my [Home.jsx](https://github.com/sarovin/Universal-React-Example/blob/master/app/components/Home/Home.jsx)

Why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are render your view on the Server
and in the server (node.js) we don't have `window` object

Change your code to render on the client side use `componentDidMount` event and flag

```
export default class AsyncMap extends Component {

  state = {
    inBrowser: false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({inBrowser: true});
  }

  yourCurrentRender() {...}

  render() {
    let res = null;
    if (this.state.inBrowser) {
      res = this.renderNewBehavior();
    } else {
      res = <span>Loading</span>;
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

Comment: Attention, setState inside componentDidMount can cause infinite loop because there's no break condition! [read more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528348/setstate-inside-of-componentdidupdate)

Answer (score -1):

> **window object is available only on the client side**

**1.*** First step is to make sure you are not doing a server side rendering, **window** object is available only on the browser.

**2.*** Second if you are using webpack and running your application on the ***webpack-dev-server*** mode your window objects are not detectable so instead of

```
localhost: 8080/webpack-dev-server/
```

try

```
localhost: 8080/
```