# ReactNativeJS: Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-native

I am working on a React-Native\Redux App

1. I am pre-populating a 's as they render. This works out fine.
   2.After population it I would like to call a dispatch action so that the value of each  is used to perform some calculations and later to be stored: I know its impossible to update state during render, but is there away I can do achieve this?

I need it to update the state as it generated the input fields.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

```
handleInputChange: function(product, productId, input){
let { currentSale, updateProductQuantity } = this.props;
let updatedCurrentSale = TransactionsService.updateProductQuantity(currentSale, product, productId, input);
let transaction = TransactionsService.packageTransaction(updatedCurrentSale);

updateProductQuantity(updatedCurrentSale, transaction)
 },
```

**updateProductQuantity** calls the disaptch action, and that's where we have a problem

```
handleQuantityValue: function(product, productId){
 let { orderSelected } = this.props;

  if(orderSelected){
     var index = orderSelected.products.findIndex(x => x.product_id==productId)
  }

  var i = index

  if( i >= 0){
      var qtty = orderSelected.products[i].product_quantity
      this.handleInputChange(product, productId, qtty).bind(this)
      return qtty.toString()
  }
  else{
        return ''
  }
},
```

returns quantity value

```
renderProducts: function(){
  let { currentUser, currentSale, orderSelected } = this.props;
  return _.map(currentSale.productSales, function(product, productId){
  var qtty = this.handleQuantityValue(product, productId)
  return <View style={Styles.questionPanel}>
    <Question 
      product={product}
      productId= {productId}
      Order={ orderSelected }
      quantity= { qtty }
      onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
    />
  </View>
}.bind(this));
```

},

This renders products and TextInput is populated with the **quantity** value. The other this is that as it renders, i should(not necessarily) dispatch an action

```
render: function(){
 let { currentSale } = this.props;
 return (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <NavBar navigator={this.props.navigator} />
    <ScrollView>
      <Text style={[Styles.dayDisplayHeader, Styles.spacing]}>
        Enter Your Sale:
      </Text>
      {this.renderProducts()}
      <Calculator 
        productSales={currentSale.productSales}
        totalSales={currentSale.totalSales}
      />
      <Button text={'Save'} whenTapped={this.handleSubmit} />
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
)
```

Comment: It sounds to me that you are trying to tackle a problem from wrong angle. Can you paste the code for your component?

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the state (you are allowed to do that) in the componentDidUpdate method: you have only to be careful and detect in which situation you have to do call the setState to avoid infinite recursion.

[setState inside componentDidUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528348/setstate-inside-of-componentdidupdate)

Comment: as I said you have to be wise and check in the componentDidUpdate when to update the state and when not!! Ideally it should be done only one time

Comment: I don't you really got my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursion. Calculating a quantity value triggers `handleInputChange`, which in turn triggers quantity calculation when re-rendering component.

I don't think you even need to trigger `handleInputChange` manually when calculating quantity value. You shouldn't.

The flow should be like this:

1. Pass data via props.
2. Calculate quantity from props when rendering.
3. `handleInputChange` only when value is changed by user.
4. Once the redux store is updated (I assume it happens via `updateProductQuantity`) new values will be passed again to the component via props (go back to step 1).

Comment: This is what I am doing at the moment, wanted to now have it done pragmatically. Lets say when the sale is delivered by a delivery guy who needs to just confirm the sale but also with ability to add more products to the list if needed.
I will stick to these for now.
Thanks.