# Repeatedly calling setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, orientation, setstate

I'm trying to figure out the orientation of background-images in a React component that are passed in as props.

I start off by creating an Image object and setting its src to the new Image:

```
  getImage() {
    const src = this.props.url;
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = src;

    this.setState({
      height: image.height,
      width: image.width
    });
  }
```

After I've updated the state with the heights and widths, I try calling `getOrientation()` inside of `componentDidUpdate()`:

```
  getOrientation() {
    const { height, width } = this.state;
    if (height > width) {
      this.setState({ orientation: "portrait" });
    } else {
      this.setState({ orientation: "landscape" });
    }
  }
```

I then get the following error:

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate.
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

[Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8zxzm48y69)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528348/setstate-inside-of-componentdidupdate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The valid function signature of `componentDidUpdate` is:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)
```

Note that the arguments have to be in the correct order. Here you can see that the previous props is the first argument, and the previous state the second one.

If you only have `componentDidUpdate(prevState)` then the variable `prevState` refers to the **previous props**, *not the previous state*. And so, to position them correctly, you need to include `prevProps` first (even if you will not use it):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  ...
}
```

For more information, see the [React.Component documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).

Comment: I have already? Check inside the componentDidUpdate() method in the Sandbox

Comment: No, your sandbox has:  `componentDidUpdate(prevState)`. Notice there's only one parameter instead of two :)