# this.setState is not working in componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

There is a some problem with this code, i think because `` setState is not working in this code.

```
this.setState({ 
  showTooltip: true, 
  toolTipsValue: message, 
  error: true 
})
```

Before click on a button

```
this.props.loginRes = {
  responseCode: 1, 
  result: {}
}
```

After Click on button

```
prevProps.loginRes = {
  responseCode: 1, 
  result: {}
}
```

```
this.props.loginRes = {
  responseCode: 1,
  result: { 
    data: {}, 
    statusCode: 1, 
    statusMessage: 'Invalid email/mobile' 
  }
}
```

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.props.loginRes !== prevProps.loginRes) {
    const message = this.props.loginRes.result.statusMessage;
    this.setState({
      showTooltip: true,
      toolTipsValue: message,
      error: true
    })
  }
}
```

Error Message 
[Error Message Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaSXE.png)

Comment: Don't use `setState` inside a `componentDidUpdate`, it'll cause infinite rerender loop btw. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528348/setstate-inside-of-componentdidupdate

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh you are right but i use condition so it's not go into infinite loop.
also i attach error screen shot plz check  it.

Comment: Could you show me the `Login.js` file, haven't seen anything wrong in your provided code yet.

Answer (score 1):

The error *this.setState is not a function* is triggered because you didn't bind the `onClick` handler. As a result `this` points to the `window` object and not to the instance of your React class component. And the `window` object doesn't have `setState()` function as its property - that's what the error message says.

To fix this error either [bind](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#bind-in-constructor-es2015) the `onClick` handler in the class constructor or [rewrite](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#class-properties-stage-3-proposal) the handler using an arrow function.

Using `setState` inside `componentDidUpdate` in the way you did should not cause endless loop.

Comment: How did you know he used `this.setState` on a `onClick`? I've thought it was in `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: componentDidUpdate does not need a binding. So it has to be anywhere else

Comment: how can i write handler using arrow function??

Comment: You can write a handler using arrow function like that: `handleClick = () => {
    console.log('Click happened'); }`

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to winwiz1. (What he says is correct).

You are commparing two objects in the componentDidUpdate function.
Comparing two objects with !== will not work.
The answer why it isn`t working can be found here: [Comparing two objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

The solution is lodash with isEqual, example can be found here:
[Depp comparison between 2 objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683075/how-to-do-a-deep-comparison-between-2-objects-with-lodash)

Comment: He's comparing 2 objects by `!==`, which will always lead to `true` because they're always not the same object, then it's an infinite loop. A nice finding :))