# component is only re-rendering when browser window is resized react

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a bar chart whose values comes from Axios get request. now this part is working fine, api is returning values fine and on initial render bar chart values are returned from api and chart renders fine but when i filter the content and set some other date values for chart it does get returned from api but component does not get re-rendered until I resize browser window even slightly. why is this happening, what resizing is doing in this case

this is how im handling change

```
 componentDidMount(){
    this.getIndividuals()
    this.getCompanies()
}

handleClick=(e)=> {  
    this.setState({clicked:true})
  }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
if((prevState.clicked!==this.state.clicked)){
    this.getIndividuals()
    this.getCompanies()
    this.setState({clicked:false})
    this.forceUpdate()
}
}
```

i tried to to use `forceupdate()` method but that is also not working

Comment: you need to show the entire code, so we could understand what's going on there

Comment: your code might be problematic since you change `clicked` to true, and you check if `clicked` is changed inside `componentDidUpdate`, you set `clicked` false and your component will render again.

Comment: @SinanYaman but im setting clicked to be true again when button is clicked

Comment: inside `componentDidUpdate` you set clicked again, therefore it re-renders and goes into componentDidUpdate again. In thta case you have prevState.clicked = false, this.state.clicked=false. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528348/setstate-inside-of-componentdidupdate) and see if that helps you.